# Show that $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}| \leq \lambda|x_n-x_{n-1}|$ with $\lambda<1$, if $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=\frac{3+2x_n}{3+x_n}$ for all $n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real number defined as follows: 
$x_1=1$, and for all $n$, $$x_{n+1}=\frac{3+2x_n}{3+x_n}$$

1. Show that there exists $\lambda \in (0,1)$, such that for all $n \geq 2$, $$|x_{n+1}-x_{n}| \leq \lambda|x_n-x_{n-1}|$$

I have shown that it converges (it's bounded and monotonic), but I'm having trouble with this part.

Comment: Did you compute $$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{3+2x_n}{3+x_n}-\frac{3+2x_{n-1}}{3+x_{n-1}}$$ and try to bound the absolute value of the result?

Comment: Oh no! I've been trying all sorts of other computations. I got $\lambda=1/5$

Comment: Please show how you got this value of lambda.

Comment: $x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{3+2x_n}{3+x_n}-\frac{3+2x_{n-1}}{3+x_{n-1}} = \frac{x_n}{3+x_n}-\frac{x_{n-1}}{3+x_{n-1}}$. Since the sequence is monotonically increasing. $\frac{x_n}{3+x_n}-\frac{x_{n-1}}{3+x_{n-1}}<\frac{x_n-x_{n-1}}{3+x_{n-1}}$
Since $x_n>1 \implies \frac{1}{3+x_n}<\frac{1}{4}$. Therefore $\frac{x_{n}-x_{n-1}}{3+x_{n-1}}<\frac{1}{4}(x_n-x_{n-1})$

My mistake. It was 1/4

Comment: Much simpler: really compute $$x_{n+1}-x_n=R(x_n,x_{n-1})\cdot(x_n-x_{n-1})$$ and find an upper bound of $R(u,v)$, valid for every $u\geqslant1$, $v\geqslant1$.

Comment: I apologise, but I don't seem to recognise this notation - $R(u,v)$

Comment: Hmm what? $ $ $ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has
$$x_{n+1}-x_n={3+2x_n\over 3+x_n}-x_n={3-x_n-x_n^2\over3+x_n}\ .\tag{1}$$
Inverting the recursion we obtain on the other hand
$$x_{n-1}={3x_n-3\over 2-x_n}\ ,$$
so that
$$x_{n-1}-x_n={3x_n-3\over 2-x_n}-x_n={x_n^2+x_n-3\over2-x_n}\ .\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ it follows that
$${|x_{n+1}-x_n|\over|x_n-x_{n-1}|}=\left|{2-x_n\over 3+x_n}\right|\leq{2\over3}\qquad(n\geq2)\ ,$$
since with $x_1=1$ all $x_n$ are positive.

Comment: For a more systematic approach (leading to the better constant $\frac3{16}$), please see my comment on main.

Comment: How did you arrive at $\frac{3}{16}$?